# How to position div div above another divs

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to set div's position like this:
[image]

but i can't set image (green box) in position.

- orange box is on top
- blue and lightgreen div are buttons
- red frame is static distant under orange box
- green box is link with image inside, covering partly blue and lightgreen buttons.
- every links must stay clickable every time.

I can't centering green image and set it above orange div partly.

Example code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o3oyuzb9/)

```
<div class="header-container">
<div class="nav-container">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="1">Click!</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <a href="2">Click!</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="header-image">
    <div class="image">
        <a href="3">Click!</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-container">
    <a href="4">Click!</a>
</div>
```

```
.nav-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: orange;
}
.logo{
    width: 25%;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    float: left;
}
.nav{
    width: 25%;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    float: right;
}
.header-image{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
}
.image{
    height: 100px;
    width: 60%;

    background: green;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.header-image a{
    padding: 40px 0;
}
.menu-container{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px red solid;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've uploaded your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o3oyuzb9/1/).

Addded the following css:

```
.header-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 20%;
}
```

also added extra margin-top for the `.menu-container`

```
.menu-container {
    margin-top: 80px; //instead of 50px
}
```

I've positioned it absolute because this way it will go wherever you want it based on the body relative positioning.

Comment: Thanks for help. I have one more little issue. Take a look at this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/o3oyuzb9/4/). Why i can't set **image** center position? and why **header-image** width is more than 100% of parent?

Comment: That's because you don't have a position relative to the parent. Add position relative to the .header-container. Also for the image add margin: 0 auto. here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o3oyuzb9/5/

Comment: Thanks for explain! Now i'm trying to apply changes for my web.

Comment: Last question, **header-image** covers violet **cart button**. Now i can't click it. Is there a way to covering only by **image**, not by **header-image?**

Answer (score 1):

adding this to `image` should work:

```
margin:0 auto;
position:relatve;
z-index:66;
margin-top:-10px
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o3oyuzb9/2/

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/x7867ssw/)

only changed the css

```
body,html{margin: 10px;}
.header-container{
    width: 100%;
}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: orange;
}
.logo{
    width: 25%;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    float: left;
}
.nav{
    width: 25%;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    float: right;
}
.header-image{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
}
.image{
    height: 100px;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -20px;
    background: green;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.header-image a{
    padding: 40px 0;
}
.menu-container{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px red solid;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

just add this to your image class:

```
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: -20px;
```